# Anyone have any experience using GCP to create a folder in Google Drive using PHP with the Drive API?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

Following the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php) I've enabled the API and installed the Google Client Library in step 2. I want to run the code from this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder).

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive( $client );

$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile( array(
'name' => 'Invoices',
'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' ) );
$file = $driveService->files->create( $fileMetadata, array( 'fields' => 'id' ) );
printf( "Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id );
```

The problem I believe is in the creation of the $client variable. I want to run the script directly from GCP without any interaction to simply create a folder in my Google Drive. Anyone know the simple way to accomplish this?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'file "credentials.json"
```

Do I need to create a "credentials.json" file to create a folder in my own drive?

Comment: You do need a credentials file indeed. You can obtain it e.g. by clicking on the "ENABLE THE DRIVE API" button in Step1 of the quickstart. This will automatically download the credentials.json file. Have you downloaded the credentials.json file and pasted it  into your working directory?

Comment: I went back through the quickstart tutorial step by step and got past the credentials error, but then it just went to another error. To much work, I was hoping they would have a method to write to Team Drives that would have been as easy as writing to Google Cloud Storage, which is nothing more than fopen 'gs://[directory]...', oh well.

Comment: I might try to use Google Apps Script, which tends to be simpler in use. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/